# I can't fix the number after the comma in C#

Tags: c#

It's my first time with C#. I got a problem and don't how to solve I hope you help me out.

Thank you in advance

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProgrammingAssignment1
{
    // IMPORTANT: Only add code in the section
    // indicated below. The code I've provided
    // makes your solution work with the 
    // automated grader on Coursera

    /// <summary>
    /// Programming Assignment 1
    /// </summary>
    class Program
    {
        // x and y coordinates for points
        static float point1X;
        static float point1Y;
        static float point2X;
        static float point2Y;

        /// <summary>
        /// Calculates angle and distance between two points
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">command-line args</param>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // loop while there's more input
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            while (input[0] != 'q')
            {
                // extract point coordinates from string
                GetInputValuesFromString(input);

                // Add your code between this comment
                // and the comment below. You can of
                // course add more space between the
                // comments as needed
                float deltaX = point2X - point1X;
                float deltaY = point2Y - point1Y;
                Double distanceBetweenPoints = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.Pow(deltaY, 2)));
                Double angleRadians = Math.Atan2((double)deltaX, (double)deltaY);
                Double angleDegrees = angleRadians * (180 / Math.PI);

                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", distanceBetweenPoints, angleDegrees);

                // Don't add or modify any code below
                // this comment
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Extracts point coordinates from the given input string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input">input string</param>
        static void GetInputValuesFromString(string input)
        {
            // extract point 1 x
            int spaceIndex = input.IndexOf(' ');
            point1X = float.Parse(input.Substring(0, spaceIndex));

            // move along string and extract point 1 y
            input = input.Substring(spaceIndex + 1);
            spaceIndex = input.IndexOf(' ');
            point1Y = float.Parse(input.Substring(0, spaceIndex));

            // move along string and extract point 2 x
            input = input.Substring(spaceIndex + 1);
            spaceIndex = input.IndexOf(' ');
            point2X = float.Parse(input.Substring(0, spaceIndex));

            // point 2 y is the rest of the string
            input = input.Substring(spaceIndex + 1);
            point2Y = float.Parse(input);

            #region Unfortunately, Mono doesn't have a Split method!
            //string[] values = input.Split(' ');
            //point1X = float.Parse(values[0]);
            //point1Y = float.Parse(values[1]);
            //point2X = float.Parse(values[2]);
            //point2Y = float.Parse(values[3]);
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get this result

[image]

but my code returns this :

```
5 5 4 4  
1.4142135623731 -135             
2 2 4 4  
2.82842712474619 45             
0 0 1 0  
1 90                       
0 0 0 1  
1 0                         
0 0 -1 0              
1 -90                      
0 0 0 -1                
1 180                   
2 2 -4 4                             
6.32455532033676 -71.565051177078              
2 2 4 -4                                    
6.32455532033676 161.565051177078                  
6 5 4 3                                      
2.82842712474619 -135                           
3 4 5 6                                
2.82842712474619 45
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is absolutely not clear what you want to achiev and what's exactly your problem.

Comment: Is your problem just the number of digits after the decimal point? I'd expect the automated grader would be fine with that, unless they explicitly asked you to limit the precision shown.

Comment: "#region Unfortunately, Mono doesn't have a Split method!" - that can't be true? [It's right here](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/main/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/string.cs#L934).

Comment: Or is your problem that the 2 2 -4 4 and 2 2 4 -4 give the answers the opposite way around to the expected output?

Comment: all i want is get that result in picture

Comment: Maybe look into `Math.Round` if your issue is significant figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must have misunderstood your programming requirements. The `5 5 4 4` is what **you enter**. Once you complete calculation you print the result. Now, it might be possible to **erase** what you have entered on console but I don't think that's the objective of exercise.

What you can do is **store** the results (I will not give hints or code since that is supposed to be exercise for you) and display them altogether.